# Growing Lamps for Indoor Growing

Tags: grow-lamp

Ikea has a brand of hydroponic start kits called vaxer. Part of their offering consists of lamps that aid in the cultivation of the plants (example1, example2 and example3). There are other companies offering lamps that should help plants grow.

When I compare the lamps from Ikea as well as others I find it hard to figure out what lamp may be preferable for my hobby projects at home. I recall seeing a documentary where it was suggested that plants prefer red and blue light because that is the colour they themselves do not emit back. This makes me wonder why the Ikea lamps don't have these colors.

I'm new at this field but I may be interested in investing in some lights for some indoor hobbying. When considering this though, what are properties of these growth lights that are important as far as plant growth goes?

In my particular situation I am not concerned with heat but more the correct type of light and the costs of electricity.

Comment: Hi cantdutchthis. I see that you've mentioned three examples of possible choices. Would you mind linking those to the products so we can see them? Thanks!

Comment: Whew! Thanks, Sue!  @cantdutchthis you need to look into T5 fluoresences

Comment: It depends on what you want to grow. The IKEA VÄXER grow lights are considered "full spectrum", which is what you want. They have white and red LEDs. See http://wastonchen.com/4421.html and https://www.instagram.com/p/BjAppmHFAPH/. They are sufficient for herbs and lettuce but not necessarily more demanding plants. Distance matters, too. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_light_integral